# Place top of stack at end of linked chain instead of beginning

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am working on a problem: create a stack using a linked chain that places the new entry (top of stack) at the end of the chain, not the beginning.  Part of the solution involves maintaining a reference to the first and last nodes and the next to last node.  Also, I cannot traverse the chain. I cannot think of a solution because I cannot think of a way to update the reference to the next to last node when the top entry is popped off the stack?

(This is a textbook question.  The beginning of the chain contains a reference to the next node.  The end of the chain's reference to the next node is null)

Answer (score 0):

Beginning and end are abstract terms.  Just initialize a node to contain the first element.  Something like the following:

```
Node tail = null;

..
..
```

Then to add a new node.

```
public void push(T val) {
  Node = new Node(val);
  Node.next = tail;
  tail = node;
}
```

You're adding it at the `tail` and then the new `node` becomes the `tail`.  Then when you iterate thru it you simply start at the tail and move towards the head using the `next` reference.

To pop the stack.

```
public T pop() {
   if (tail != null) {
      object = tail.object;
      tail = tail.next;  
   }
   return null;
}
```

You will need to create a generic class Node.  And you may want to have an `isEmpty()` method.